# Sql query indexing is not working properly

Tags: mysql

I am facing a problem with indexing. I am not getting why the indexing is not working for the same query some times.

In below case indexing is working

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `table_name`.* FROM `table_name`
WHERE (created_date between '2018-08-11' and '2018-08-11');
```

| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type |

### possible_keys                  | key                   | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                              |

|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_name        | NULL       | ref  | index_table_name_created_date | table_name_created_date | 4       | const |   11 |     1.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
    +----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
    1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

Same thing if i increase the date range indexing is not working like below one

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `table_name`.* FROM `table_name`
WHERE (created_date between '2018-08-11' and '2018-09-11');
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

| id | select_type | table      | partitions  | type | 
possible_keys                  | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
    +----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+------------------
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_name | NULL       | ALL  | index_table_name_created_date | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1233 |     0.30 | Using where |
    +----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
    1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Can anyone help me how to handle this case?  Because of this to my query is taking longer time to execute.

Comment: `my query is taking longer time to execute` ... Actually both queries finish almost immediately.  You may want to change your example such that it highlights the two behaviors better.

Answer (score 1):

The major concept here is that you are doing `SELECT *` on your table, which tells MySQL that you want to return *all* columns from the table, for each record returned.  While you may have an index on the `created_date` column, MySQL may choose not use it with `SELECT *`.  The reason for this is that once MySQL traverses down the B-tree to reach each leaf node, only data for the `created_date` is present there.  For the other columns, MySQL would have to do an additional seek to the clustered index to get the data for the other columns.  As a result, using the index might not help the query.

As to why the index was used in the first case, the optimizer may have recognized that there was only a single matching record, and then decided to use the index anyway.  Really, your example would be better if many records were being returned from the query.

Here is an example of a query which *could* use the index:

```
SELECT created_date
FROM yourTable
WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2018-08-11' AND '2018-08-11';
```

In this case, the index contains all the columns we are trying to select.  If you wanted to select another column, say `col1`, then you could add `col1` to the index (such that the index would now be on `(created_date, col1)`), and then the following query could also use the index:

```
SELECT created_date, col1
FROM yourTable
WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2018-08-11' AND '2018-08-11';
```

Comment: I tried by adding select columns also. If you see the example mentioned above first query type is range . But in second query type is null.

Comment: You're missing the point of my answer, maybe I should edit it.  MySQL generally _can't_ use your index.  You got faked out by the first query; the index cannot generally be used at all for this query.

Comment: I agree with the example you mentioned above. If i add created date to select case it takes the indexing. But if i have more conditions in where clause it won't work. How can i handle in that case.

SELECT created_date, col1
FROM yourTable
WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2018-08-11' AND '2018-08-11' and col2 = 1;

Comment: You might have to add `col2` to the index.  It really depends on whether or not MySQL can use that index.